# function with condition as parameter issue

Tags: php, mysql

i have come across this function that i want use but i want short it DESC. i have tried many ways without success. I have tried to create third parameter but that does not work. please can someone help?

```
public function getRows($conditions = array()){
        $sql = 'SELECT ';
        $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
        $sql .= ' FROM '.$this->tblName;
        if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' WHERE ';
            $i = 0;
            foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
                $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
                $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
                $i++;
            }
        }

        if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by']; 
        }

        if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit']; 
        }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit']; 
        }

        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        if(array_key_exists("return_type",$conditions) && $conditions['return_type'] != 'all'){
            switch($conditions['return_type']){
                case 'count':
                    $data = $result->num_rows;
                    break;
                case 'single':
                    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    break;
                default:
                    $data = '';
            }
        }else{
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
        return !empty($data)?$data:false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the rows to be ordered in descending sort according to the conditions you set? If so simply while calling the function `getRows` add an indice to the array `$conditions` as `$conditions['order_by'] = 'my_awesome_column DESC'`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra 'parameter' to the `$conditions` array you pass in and detect it in the following code...

```
if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by']; 
    if(array_key_exists("sort_order",$conditions)){
         $sql .= ' '.$conditions['sort_order']; 
}
```

So when you call it add a 'sort_order' element...

```
$conditions['where'] = array( 'id' => $_POST['id']);
$conditions['order_by'] = 'id';
$conditions['sort_order'] = 'desc';
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answer but, i have tried the two solutions above, they didn't change the order of the query. I wanted the result to be descending based on post id. thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you set the column name in `'order_by' => 'id'` to be the post id?  If you show how you call this function in your question, this may help.

Comment: Here is how i called it.

Comment: $conditions['where'] = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],'order_by' => 'id', 'sort_order' =>'desc'
    ); post[id is the id of the post retrieved from db]

Comment: I have tried this one too.$conditions['where'] = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],'order_by' => $_POST['id'], 'sort_order' =>'desc'
    ); but still not working

Comment: Yes, the last solution worked. Thank a lot for your help, i appreciate it.